# Meter una consulta PostgreSQL en una variable en Java

Tags: java, postgresql

Tengo una tabla alumnos con dos campos, id y nombre.

La tabla alumnos la meto en un combobox

```
Conexion conexionBD = new Conexion();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos;";
    try {
        conexion = conexionBD.dataSource.getConnection();
        pst = conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        //LLenamos nuestro ComboBox          
        jcListas.addItem("Seleccione una opción");

        //Recorremos todos los registros de la tabla
        while (rs.next()) {                                 
            jcListas.addItem(rs.getObject("nombre"));
        }
```

El combobox me muestra el nombre, funciona bien.

Tengo un botón, el cuál toma el valor del combobox(nombre del alumno) pero yo quiero obtener el id del alumno, no el index del combo, tampoco el nombre del alumno, ya que tengo una función con un parámetro de tipo entero que toma el id del alumno.

```
java.sql.Statement stmt = conexion.createStatement();                                            

                rs = stmt.executeQuery(cadena);
               int valor3 = rs.getInt("id");                  
             String query = "SELECT * FROM fun_eligeAlumno(valor3);";
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                if (rs.next()) {
                    this.jcCargaListas.addItem(rs.getString("id"));
                    if (rs.getInt(1) == 0) {
                        jlEstado.setText(rs.getString(2));
                    } else {
                        jlEstado.setText("");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,rs.getString(2));
                    }
```

Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Ocurre que del modo que cargas los alumnos en el combo estás perdiendo los ids ya que solamente metes ahí el nombre.

Para solucionar esto debes crear una clase con la que puedas almacenar tanto el id como el nombre del alumno. Luego esta clase debe sobrescribir el método `Object#toString()` para que este retorne el `String` que quieres mostrar en el combo para cada alumno.

```
public class Alumno {
    private int id;
    private String nombre;

    public Alumno(int id, String nombre) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    // Setters y Getters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nombre;// Con esto el combo mostrará el nombre del alumno tal como lo tienes ahora
    }
}
```

Luego debes modificar un poco el código donde cargas los alumnos y los metes al combo.

```
// Notar que omití el resto del código que tu muestras

//LLenamos nuestro ComboBox          
jcListas.addItem(new Alumno(-1, "Seleccione una opción"));

//Recorremos todos los registros de la tabla
while (rs.next()) {                                 
    jcListas.addItem(new Alumno(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("nombre")));
}
```

Ahora solo debes tener en cuenta de que cuando obtengas el elemento seleccionado este será un objeto de tipo `Alumno` y no un `String` como ócurría hasta ahora.